# Calling Messagebox.Show from a Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I've just found this gem in a form in our codebase. I think I already know the answer to this: I'm pretty sure that calling MessageBox.Show in a background thread is a terrible idea, but could someone confirm and clarify for me?

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_FileScanner.IsSending)
    {
        Trace("Cannot close form because: Transferring files.");
        e.Cancel = true;
        Task<DialogResult> t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MessageBox.Show("Transferring files"));
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know you should only call the UI from the UI thread, otherwise you can get anything from exceptions to unexpected results :) I wonder what's the reason behind this code snippet... ;)

Comment: I am not entirely sure but TaskScheduler may actually schedule the task to use UI Synchronization context and the code may execute on UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be little-to-no point in doing this and in fact potential dangers - considering the heavy work is actually being processed on non-UI-blocking threads using Tasks (as should be the case) then the very time you want the form to block input (depending on requirements, but this still stands regardless of dialog modality) until acknowledgement is when you'd do this on the STAThread.

Comment: Exactly: the problem here being that all the heavy work is being done on the UI thread (thus blocking), and our 'senior' developer's solution is to push the MessageBox.Show call to a background thread.